# Not able to set custom color in SimpleArcLoader in android

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Here is a SimpleArcLoader library I am using as progress bar.

https://github.com/generic-leo/SimpleArcLoader

Here is my code:

```
int[] colors = {R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorPrimary};

ArcConfiguration configuration = new ArcConfiguration(getActivity());
configuration.setColors(colors);

SimpleArcDialog  mDialog = new SimpleArcDialog(getActivity());
mDialog.setConfiguration(configuration);
mDialog.show();
```

This always gives me a gray color. I also tried with other colors but same result.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65y6W.png)

Is my input is wrong? Or is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must declare your array colors like this : 
 private int mColors[] = {Color.parseColor("#F90101"),Color.parseColor("#0266C8")};